# python_list to array error

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

here my code:

```
ldata = []
for line in f:
    tmp = line.strip().split(',')
    ldata.append([float(i) for i in tmp[2:]])
print len(ldata),len(ldata[0])
cc = np.array(ldata)
print cc.shape
d = cc*0.25
```

The result:

```
4345,560
(4345,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Che\workspace\recali.py", line 62, in <module>
    d = cc*0.25
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

The shape of the array should (4345,560), while it shows (4345,)....and can not multiply a float. Why did this happen?

Comment: What do you expect `d = cc*0.25` to do?

Comment: I want convert the list to numpy array and then do later calculation(didn't mention in above, the d = cc*0.25 is just a example~)

Comment: if you're multiplying the entire array by 0.25, try `d = [x * 0.25 for x in cc] `

Comment: If you're trying to reduce every element by a factor of 4, you can just change the 4th line to `ldata.append([float(i) * 0.25 for i in tmp[2:]])`?

Comment: @RussellHickey which stil raise same problem, I printed the type of cc[0], it was list

Comment: sorry try `d = [[x * 0.25 for x in c] for c in cc]` I forgot it was a list within a list

Comment: @RussellHickey, actually, I also checked the type of cc, which shows <type 'numpy.ndarray'>.  I believe  a array shoud can multiply a float  directly

Comment: @Owen a nparray can multiply float only if its elements are numbers, in your case the ldata elements are list that's why you are getting this error

Comment: @Phylogenesis, yes! It seems like a array but containing list. the type of cc is array, while the type of c[0] is list.............so what should i do?

Comment: one of those lists in your lists of lists is not the same length as the others. If you want `numpy.array()` to make you a 2d array from a list of lists, they have to be all the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere, in your list of lists, is a list of the wrong length

```
In [3]: numpy.array([range(i) for i in range(50)])*.25 #these lists are of different length
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-29e79fee6349> in <module>()
----> 1 numpy.array([range(i) for i in range(50)])*.25

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

In [4]: numpy.array([range(50) for i in range(50)])*.25 #these lists are of the same length
Out[4]: 
array([[  0.  ,   0.25,   0.5 , ...,  11.75,  12.  ,  12.25],
       [  0.  ,   0.25,   0.5 , ...,  11.75,  12.  ,  12.25],
       [  0.  ,   0.25,   0.5 , ...,  11.75,  12.  ,  12.25],
       ..., 
       [  0.  ,   0.25,   0.5 , ...,  11.75,  12.  ,  12.25],
       [  0.  ,   0.25,   0.5 , ...,  11.75,  12.  ,  12.25],
       [  0.  ,   0.25,   0.5 , ...,  11.75,  12.  ,  12.25]])
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting `(4345,)` as an output is because the lists inside of the array are not the same length, hence it cannot give you the second number.

For example:
Say the array is `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9,10]]`. The shape cannot give you the second digit because it can be both `3` or `4`.

As for the `d =` part you should be using `d = [[x * 0.25 for x in c] for c in cc]`. It will iterate through each list in the array and return a new list multiplied by `0.25`.

Comment: You can totally multiply a numpy array by a float and it'll work.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen The numpy array isn't holding other numpy arrays, it's holding Python ones.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that `ldata` list items is itself a list(`ldata` is a list of lists).

If you want `ldata` to be 2-d array, then you can do this

```
ldata_new = []
for data in ldata:
    cc = np.array(data)
    d = cc*0.25
    ldata_new.append(d)
cc = np.array(ldata_new)
```

Now `cc` will be of `numpy.ndarray` type

Comment: what i want is a 2-d array,  so I can not do this

Comment: Ok, then you should do it for individual lists of your `ldata` list rather than multiplying a 2-d list by a float